# Changing displayed year to the next year on a specific date each year

Tags: php, date

Ok y'all, I have a quandary. I have an application that needs to update the year to 2017-2018 that is displayed on a button on October 1, 2016 at 12am. It has to stay that way until next year on the same Oct. 1 date which it will update again to 2018-2019. How do I write this in php?

Comment: Could you show the code for the current button? This will at least give people something to build on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
//the year from is the current year
$yearFrom = date("Y");

//if it's october or later, make the year from NEXT year
if (date("n")>=10) $yearFrom++;

//the year to is always the year after the year from
$yearTo = $yearFrom + 1;
```

Then inside your button

```
echo $yearFrom."-".$yearTo;
```

Comment: Here is what is currently the code: 
'<h4><?php echo date("Y"); ?>-<?php echo date("Y",strtotime("+1 year")); ?></h4>